# How to match browser's window center with <div> center

Tags: jquery, css, html, center

I have a div, which is in most cases bigger than user's browser window size.

What I want is - when user enters this page the center of his browser's window should match the center of the div (as displayed [here](http://i43.tinypic.com/2rcr9q9.jpg)).

So after entering the website user should be able to scroll up/down/left/right.

How is it possible to do so? Many thanks!

Comment: If you show us what you have achieved so far, it will greatly help us to offer relevant advice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite easy actually: http://jsfiddle.net/enguerranws/fRn49/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divHeight = $('div').height();
  var divWidth = $('div').width();
  $('div').css({
      'top' : - divHeight/2,
      'left' : - divWidth/2
  });

});
```

In some words : the center of an element is the half of its height and the half of its width. Note that that div got a position : absolute.

EDIT : I think you can do the same only with CSS.